# Menu options whitened after installing theme

Tags: themes

I have installed some themes like (hope, Ambiance blue etc) in my ubuntu 12.10.
No matter which theme i install, the menu options are whitened so also the options appearing on right click. I am giving a screen shot for better understanding.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n4v3js3twexzk01/bug.png

can any one help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That specific theme has not been updated by its author to work correctly with GTK+ v3.6 (the version that Ubuntu 12.10 uses). GNOME is the faulty here, because with every minor GTK+ release they are breaking all the themes, wasting everyone’s time.

Comment: that means no solution?

Comment: @ioweyou I guess you should contact the theme developer (look for them in the README) and kindly ask them to update their theme so it works with the latest GTK+.